# Save JavaScript variable to file via php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am fairly new to programming, and was trying to save a JavaScript variable to an existing file:

```
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var data = inputs
function saveLists(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "save.php",
    data: "data",
    success: function(){
        alert("success!")},
    error: function(){
        alert("Failed!")},
    dataType: "text"
})
}
</script>
```

I define the inputs variable earlier, and I am using POST method and the following php server side:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST["data"];
$f = fopen('Inputs.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($f, $data);
fclose($f);
?>
```

When I call the saveLists() function the success alert comes up, but the data is not written to Inputs.txt. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `data: "data"` so you are just sending the string "data" and PHP is complaining about an undefined index but you're ignoring it.

Comment: `data` needs to be a query string e.g. `data: 'data=something'` or an object e.g. `data: { data: 'something' }`.

Comment: If you get the `success:` then it's most likely the php is not handling it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is trying to read an index which doesn't exist, `data` is not a valid index & key. Try something like this:

```
data: {
    "data" : data
}
```

Also, don't trust all code that the server receives in PHP.